# Como puedo hacer para volver a escribir mi usuario y contraseña si me equivoco?

Tags: sql, visual

si tengo un usuario y una contraseña, pero sin querer digito mal el usuario y la contraseña como hago para poder digitar de nuevo.

Este es mi código y a la hora de querer poner correcto el usuario o la contraseña se sale y no me vuelve a parecer el form. Soy nueva en esto por si las dudas.

En vez de un botón estoy usando una imagen tipo Gif.

```
Private Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "CT" And TextBox2.Text = "ctmy" Then
            Form4.Show()
        Else
            If TextBox1.Text <> "CT" Then
                MsgBox("El nombre de usuario es incorrecto")
            Else
                If TextBox2.Text <> "ctmy" Then
                    MsgBox("La contraseña es incorrecta")
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Me.Hide()
    End Sub
```

Sería genial si alguien me puede ayudar. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de equivocarte en el ingreso de datos, mandas una alerta, y al cerrarse esa alerta, puedes cerrar y abrir el formulario nuevamente, refrescandolo de este modo.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando dices *"se sale"*, es porque tú, con tu código, lo cierras, al invocar al método `Hide()` que, como su nombre indica, oculta el formulario.

Una posible solución es que, entonces, lo cierres solamente si el usuario y contraseña son correctas, moviendolo del lugar donde lo invocas:

```
Private Sub PictureBox5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox5.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = "CT" And TextBox2.Text = "ctmy" Then
            Form4.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            If TextBox1.Text <> "CT" Then
                MsgBox("El nombre de usuario es incorrecto")
            Else
                If TextBox2.Text <> "ctmy" Then
                    MsgBox("La contraseña es incorrecta")
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```